# firefox addon for http requests

Tags: firefox-addon

Does anyone know firefox addon which could give ability to change http post request on fly(http header fields, parameters, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/). It does exactly what you are looking for.